# ImportError: cannot import name '_obtain_input_shape' when using Keras in Colab

Tags: python, keras, import

I'm trying to implement Inception v3 in Colab and this issue keeps coming up. It's a common problem, I know, but *none* of the suggestions seemed to resolve the bug. Some worth mentioning:

Changing
`from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape`
to
`from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape`
or downgrading Keras from 2.2.2 to 2.2.0 or frankly any other version, I just cannot beat this thing.
Does anyone have up-to-date info on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following solution.

**1. Modify the import statement**

change the import statement

```
from keras.applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

to the following statement

```
from keras_applications.imagenet_utils import _obtain_input_shape
```

**2. Use the argument of require_flatten=include_top to replace include_top=include_top**

```
  # Determine the proper input shape
    input_shape = _obtain_input_shape(
        input_shape,
        default_size=299,
        min_size=139,
        data_format=K.image_data_format(),
        # -include_top=include_top
        require_flatten=include_top)
```

**3.Put the library of keras_applications into your working directory. You can download the library with the weblink as follows.**

https://github.com/keras-team/keras-applications/tree/master/keras_applications

Cheers!